# Angular 10. How to navigate to a component's sections via a different component's anchor link tag?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass, anchor

app.component.html

```
<!--I wish to keep this structure like this, because menu.component has position sticky at top: 0-->
<app-home></app-home>
<app-menu></app-menu>
<app-about></app-about>
<app-projects></app-projects>
<app-contact></app-contact>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

menu.component.html

```
<!--On anchor link click, navigate to corresponding  component-->
<nav>
    <a>Home</a>
    <a>About</a>
    <a>Projects</a>
    <a>Contact</a>
</nav>
```

home.component.html, about.component.html, projects.component.html, contact.component.html

```
<!--Basic structure-->
<section>
    <p>component works!</p>
</section>
```

A Link to the basic structure of the web-site
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ufce4g

I would have shared a link to the actual web-site(my personal web-site), but i don't know if i am allowed.

Comment: Have you had a look at Angular Router? I believe this is what you want. See https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I wish to render all components in app.component.html, without using <router-outlet></router-outlet>. Because otherwise the router renders just one component.  And from my menu.component.html on anchor click to scroll the corresponding component to top of the window, like the native anchor href behavior.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a shared service between you `menu` component and your `app` component.

It would work like this:

1. Dispatch a notification when a navigation item is clicked in you `menu` component;
2. Listen for notification in your app component. When a new notification is received, scroll to the corresponding component on your page.

Something like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavigationService {
  private _navigation$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('home');
  navigation$ = this._navigation$.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updateNavigation(item) {
    this._navigation$.next(item);
  }

}
```

In your `menu` component, call the `updateNavigation` method of `NavigationService` whenever a navigation item is clicked.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  // ...
})
export class MenuComponent {

  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) {}

  // Call this method whenever one of your navigation items is clicked
  // in your template.
  // 
  // navigationItem could, for example, be a string/enum corresponding to
  // the component that must be scrolled into view
  handleNavigationItemClick(navigationItem: string) {
    this.navigationService.updateNavigation(navigationItem);
  }
}
```

Finally, in your `app` component, listen for a navigation item update and scroll to the component.

```
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navigationService.navigation$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    ).subscribe(navigationItem => this.scrollIntoView(navigationItem))
  }

  private scrollIntoView(component) {
    // Scrolling logic ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The rxjs is over me. I read some topics about what is the best practice to share communication between components. And there are very different approaches. For my issue i just basically imported the  components in app.component.ts that i needed via ```@ViewChild(Component)``` , attached an onclick listener for the menu buttons, and  over if statements scrolled in to view the corresponding component's element.